# need to convert sql time from decimal to hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
cast( DateDiff( MINUTE, S.PlannedStartDateTime, S.PlannedEndDateTime) as decimal (12,6)) / 60 else null end) BasicHours
```

which brings back the date time as decimal i.e. `31.416666`, but this really needs to be `31hr 25mins`

How can my code display the correct date format?

Comment: SQL Server does not have a type that represents more than 24 hours.  You will need to do this conversion yourself, into a string.

Comment: i missed some off, i'm trying to get the time difference also S.PlannedStartDateTime, S.PlannedEndDateTime - from the start time and end time.

Comment: S.PlannedStartDateTime and S.PlannedEndDateTime are DATETIME or DATETIME2?

Comment: Itzik Ben-Gan has a function that does exactly that... http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/how-compute-date-and-time-difference-parts?NL=TECH-007a&Issue=TECH-007a_20170907_TECH-007a_601&sfvc4enews=42&cl=article_1&utm_rid=CPMIN000072051854&utm_campaign=89761&utm_medium=email&elq2=81337fc9b73a4038abb9045c11d092c6

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,StartTime datetime,EndTime datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2017-01-01 20:30:15','2017-01-05 22:58:35'),
(2,'2017-01-01 09:00:00','2017-01-01 17:00:00'),
(3,'2017-01-01 09:00:00','2017-01-01 09:05:00')

Select A.ID
      ,Duration =  concat(Seconds/3600,'hr ',Seconds%3600/60,'mins')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values (DateDiff(SECOND,StartTime,EndTime))) B (Seconds)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Duration
1   98hr 28mins
2   8hr 0mins
3   0hr 5mins
```

> **EDIT if you don't want the CROSS APPLY**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Duration =  concat(DateDiff(SECOND,StartTime,EndTime)/3600,'hr ',DateDiff(SECOND,StartTime,EndTime)%3600/60,'mins')
 From  @YourTable A
```

**One Should Note:**, there is a limitation ... the max value of an INT (or 2,147,483,647).  So provided your span does not exceed:

```
Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
68      0       19      3       14      7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of [Itzik Ben Gan's DATEDIFFPARTS function](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/how-compute-date-and-time-difference-parts)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_DateDiffParts 
/* =======================================================================================================
04/06/2017 JL, Created.
    Code based off of a similar function created by Itzik Ben-Gan. 
    (http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/how-compute-date-and-time-difference-parts)
======================================================================================================= */
(
    @dt1 AS DATETIME2(7), 
    @dt2 AS DATETIME2(7)
)
 RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN
    SELECT
        DateDiffParts = CONCAT(
            CAST(V.yy AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.yy,
            CAST(V.mm AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.mm,
            CAST(V.dd AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.dd,
            CAST(V.hh AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.hh,
            CAST(V.mi AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.mi,
            CAST(V.ss AS VARCHAR(10)) + L.ss
            )
    FROM
        ( VALUES ( 
                    CASE WHEN @dt1 > @dt2 THEN @dt2 ELSE @dt1 END, 
                    CASE WHEN @dt1 > @dt2 THEN @dt1 ELSE @dt2 END
                ) 
            ) D (dt1, dt2)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 
                    CAST(D.dt1 AS TIME), 
                    CAST(D.dt2 AS TIME), 
                    DATEDIFF(yy, D.dt1, D.dt2), 
                    DATEDIFF(mm, D.dt1, D.dt2), 
                    DATEDIFF(dd, D.dt1, D.dt2) 
                ) 
            ) A1 (t1, t2, yydiff, mmdiff, dddiff)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 
                    CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, A1.yydiff, D.dt1) > D.dt2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                    CASE WHEN DATEADD(mm, A1.mmdiff, D.dt1) > D.dt2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                    CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, A1.dddiff, D.dt1) > D.dt2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                ) 
            ) A2 (subyy, submm, subdd)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 
                    CAST(86400000000000 AS BIGINT) * A2.subdd 
                    + (CAST(1000000000 AS BIGINT) * DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00', A1.t2) + DATEPART(ns, A1.t2)) 
                    - (CAST(1000000000 AS BIGINT) * DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00', A1.t1) + DATEPART(ns, A1.t1)) 
                ) 
            ) A3 (nsdiff)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                    A1.yydiff - A2.subyy,
                    (A1.mmdiff - A2.submm) % 12,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(mm, A1.mmdiff - A2.submm,D.dt1), D.dt2) - A2.subdd,
                    A3.nsdiff / CAST(3600000000000 AS BIGINT),
                    A3.nsdiff / CAST(60000000000 AS BIGINT) % 60,
                    CAST(A3.nsdiff / 1000000000.0 % 60.0 AS DECIMAL(9,1))
                ) 
            ) V (yy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.yy > 1 THEN ' years, '
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 THEN ' year, '
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.mm > 1 THEN ' months, '
                        WHEN V.mm > 0 THEN ' month, '
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 THEN ' months, '
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.dd > 1 THEN ' days, '
                        WHEN V.dd > 0 THEN ' day, '
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 OR V.mm > 0 THEN ' days, '
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.hh > 1 THEN ' hours, '
                        WHEN V.hh > 0 THEN ' hour, '
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 OR V.mm > 0 OR V.dd > 0 THEN ' hours, '
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.mi > 1 THEN ' mins, '
                        WHEN V.mi > 0 THEN ' min, '
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 OR V.mm > 0 OR V.dd > 0 OR V.hh > 0 THEN ' mins, '
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN V.ss > 1 THEN ' secs'
                        WHEN V.ss > 0 THEN ' sec'
                        WHEN V.yy > 0 OR V.mm > 0 OR V.dd > 0 OR V.hh > 0 OR V.mi > 0 THEN ' secs'
                    END
                )
            ) L (yy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss);
GO
```

Sample query...

```
SELECT 
    ddp.DateDiffParts
FROM
    dbo.tfn_DateDiffParts('2017-06-01 08:22:11.12345', '2017-06-02 11:30:25.32145') ddp;
```

And the function output...

```
DateDiffParts
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 day, 3 hours, 8 mins, 14.2 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query to get your result -

```
select  CAST (CONCAT( datediff(HH,'2017-09-05 21:55:00','2017-09-07 08:16:00') , '.' , 60- datediff(MINUTE,'2017-09-05 21:55:00','2017-09-07 08:16:00')%60) as decimal (12,6)) 

--OUTPUT
35.390000
```